# Wordpress add_action call function more than 1 time

Tags: wordpress

I have function which count page views in Wordrpess, but when I reload page `add_action()` call function 5 times, I not know why.

```
<?php
add_action('wp', 'wp125_adview');
function wp125_adview(){
    global $wpdb;

    $adtable_name = $wpdb->prefix . "wp125_ads";
    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    if(isset($_POST['unique_hidden_field'])) {
        $update = "UPDATE ". $adtable_name ." SET views = views+1 WHERE status!=0";
        $results = $wpdb->query( $update );
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have hooked your function call into the 'wp' action hook.
It might be better to use something that should run only once per page, e.g.

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'wp125_adview');
```

Comment: @Lopezito - that implies that either your page is being called 5 times, or the wordpress code in the page is being executed 5 times. See if you can check this.

Comment: Mhm I try add to footer function `wp125_adview()` but it also executed 5 times, I not understant what happened and how it works

Comment: @Lopezito - It sounds like either you have a loop somewhere, or you have included the function call in other places too. It's easy to get tangled up in the various templates that can exist for your theme, so check them carefully, and if necessary use a very basic template with no header/footers to act as a "clean" page and build up from there.