# Wordpress how to add a page counter

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, counter, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm using a custom number field (generated by Jet Engine plugin) to track the number of times a page was loaded.

On my `functions.php` file I am using this code:

```
$count = get_post_meta("706", 'counter', true );
if(!is_admin() && !current_user_can('administrator')){
$count++;
update_post_meta("706", 'counter', $count );
}
```

'counter' is the field name.

I am using the `if(!is_admin)` so it will not count my back end testings.

My main issue is that the counter is not consistent, and although for most of the times it counts in steps of `1`, it sometimes skips and count `2`, `3` or `4` on a single page load.

This is a link to my test page:

https://oferziv.com/ofer/test/test3/

What am I missing here?

Comment: But I can see the counter is working fine on your page.

Comment: Thanks @Bhautik. if you try to refresh a number of times or exit the page and reload, you will see that it sometimes 'jumps' in 2, 3 or 4 instead of 1

Comment: The page counter only updates if someone visits the page.

Comment: In what kind of hook have you wrapped your code in? BTW, `current_user_can('administrator')` will always evaluate to false since it doesn't seem to be a [valid capability](https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/#capabilities).

Comment: Thanks @nosurs. I did not wrap my code in a hook. php is not my strong side, i'm afraid. about the current_user_can, all I wanted is that the counter will not count refresh on the backend. if you have any suggestions, I would love some help

Comment: Where do you hook it to? I always use the ```wp_head``` action hook.

Comment: @Ruvee its not hooked to any template. the code is linked to a meta field. the meta field is printed on the front via dynamic element (Crocoblock)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like i said, i always use the `wp_head` action hook and it works seamlessly fine!

```php
function my_counter_function()
{
  if (is_admin() || current_user_can('activate_plugins')) return;

  $counter = get_post_meta("706", 'counter', true);

  if (empty($counter)) {
    $counter = 1;
    update_post_meta("706", 'counter', $counter);
  } else {
    $counter++;
    update_post_meta("706", 'counter', $counter);
  }
}

add_action('wp_head', 'my_counter_function'); // This is the action hook i was talking about!
```

Comment: I see. thanks so much! this works perfect for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you'll want to wrap everything inside a proper hook, like so:

```
// Runs on every page request after we have a valid user.

add_action('init', function () {

    // Return early if we're in the backend...

    if (is_admin()) {

        return;
    }

    // ...or the current user has admin capabilities 

    if (current_user_can('activate_plugins')) {

        return;
    }

    // Otherwise, update counter

    $count = get_post_meta("706", 'counter', true );
    $count++;
    
    update_post_meta("706", 'counter', $count );
});
```

About how to use hooks, see:

- https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/
- https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

For checking user privileges, see:

- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_user_can/
- https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/#capabilities
- https://dev.to/lucagrandicelli/why-isadmin-is-totally-unsafe-for-your-wordpress-development-1le1

Comment: Thank you so much for that! it works in not counting my hits when I'm logged in, but it still sometimes counts more than 1 when reloading (testing on incognito). can you tell why is that?

Comment: Have you had a chance to look into [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024526/wordpress-add-action-call-function-more-than-1-time)? Anyway, I'd suggest the same as this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15025002/3323348) does and try a different hook like the mentioned `wp_footer` (instead of  `init`).  Make sure to read the comments to this answer, too - sounds a lot like the issues you've run into.